# How heap buffer overflows protections work?

Tags: linux, heap-memory, glibc, buffer-overflow

Running :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char* file_one = malloc(10);
    char* file_two = malloc(10);

    strcpy(file_one, argv[1]);

    printf("file_one addresss is: %p\n", file_one);
    printf("file_two addresss is: %p\n", file_two);
    printf("Difference is %ld\n", (file_two-file_one));
    printf("File_two has: %s", file_two);

    free(file_one);
    free(file_two);
}
```

and running it using different values insted of `15`:

```
./heap_overflow $(python -c "print('A'*15+'koko')")
```

cause glibc to raise different errors (sometimes `munmap_chunk` sometimes `double free or corruption`) and exit. also overflowing buffer by more than 10 but less than a specific number seems to do Nothing so what exactly are these mechanisms and how they work. I guess they are like stack canaries  but can't see why their behavior is different when overflow amount differs. and if so where are they place in relation to `difference`.

Comment: They typically aren't intended as protection mechanisms or "canaries" per se, just that malloc happens to store its own internal data in the space before and after allocated blocks, and it does some consistency checks at various points and aborts when they fail.  If you want the exact details, you can read the source code for glibc's malloc.

Comment: But the values stored there aren't particularly meant to be random or secure, and a well-designed exploit is very likely to be able to set them in such a way that the consistency checks pass.  Indeed overwriting them with just the right values is how heap overflow attacks do their job.

Comment: The other point is that this data typically consists of pointers or long integers and therefore must be aligned to say 8 or 16 bytes.  The start of the allocated block is also aligned to some power of 2, maybe 8 or 16 again.  So if you request 10 bytes, there'll actually be 16 bytes before the aligned metadata begins.  If you then scribble over the intervening 6 bytes, typically nothing will happen.  In effect, your allocation size is rounded up to a multiple of 16.  (It should go without saying that you should not *rely* on such behavior!)

Comment: You simply should think that there are really no checks by default. If you need some support to find heap corruption or other memory problems, use tools like valgrind or instrumented libraries or sanitizer options from the compiler. If you once see a error message from not instrumented code, it is time to use the tools :-)